# Установка QEMU на ios через ish или как либо ещё

Tags: linux, ios, qemu

Я не особо разбираюсь в линуксе в целом и в ish в частности, я пытался установить qemu на ish, но безрезультатно, прошу объясните в чем заключается установка qemu в линуксе и как это можно сделать в ish или где либо еще, если предложите альтернативный вариант, то это тоже будет прекрасно. Если будут необходимы какая либо доп информация, я могу ее предоставить

Answer (score 2):

> iSH is a project to get a Linux shell environment running locally on
> your iOS device, using a usermode x86 emulator.

Как следует из описания, эта штуковина уже является эмулятором, так что запустить вутри нее еще один эмулятор, да еще и аппаратный (которым и является qemu в большинстве инкарнаций) будет малореально / трудно.

Короче, QEMU место в линкуксе, который запущен прямо на железе, остальное уже - удел любителей корчинга | людей, которые знают, что они делают.

Comment: QEMU это обычная программа, которая может запускаться полностью в user-mode: без аппаратной поддержки и модулей в ядре. Но всё равно не стоит заниматься этим)